# Wpf Cross-Thread not showing DataGrid value

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

This is my code :

```
    public void AddToGrid(string value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value);   //Message is showing with correct value
        dgrComponentList.Dispatcher.Invoke(new AddToGridDelegate(AddToGridSolid), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, value);
    }
    private delegate void AddToGridDelegate(string value);
    private void AddToGridSolid(string value)
    {
        ((List<object>)this.dgrComponentList.ItemsSource).Add(new { ComponentName = value });
    }
```

This not is not working when I am calling AddToGrid method from a thread.
But without thread if I am calling

`((List<object>)this.dgrComponentList.ItemsSource).Add(new { ComponentName = value });`

its working perfectly. Where am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

EDIT: I have just discovered, values are storing there but somehow its not showing into the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid did not know that there is a new object added to the collection. Either implement an inotify collection changed or use an observable collection to store the objects.

Comment: Wow genius. You saved my atleast 2 hours buddy. I would give you 100 points if I had the power. Truly life saver. Thanks.